# what is correct and efficient usage of CustomScrollView in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-sliver

CustomScrollView in flutter takes an argument as "slivers" which is an array of widgets (sliver widgets to be precise)

everywhere i see developers put a single SliverList as the only element in that array, and put all the scrollable content inside the delegate.

What happens if i put multiple SliverLists and SliverGrids and SlivertoBoxAdapters inside? i know it works but i wanna know about **efficiency** and **recycling behavior** of the ScrollView. SliverList delegate does some recycling and lazy-building for its own children but what about the entire Scrollable Content?

```
return CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    header1, // SliverToBoxAdapter
    sliverList1,
    sliverStaggeredGrid1,
    header2, // SliverToBoxAdapter
    sliverList2,
    header3, // SliverToBoxAdapter
    sliverGrid1,
    footer, // SliverToBoxAdapter
  ],
);
```

- does it build all the slivers(the ones directly inside slivers array) even if they are not visible?
- if it does, do they build their children ( im using delegates, but what about BoxAdapters? )
- what should i do if i have multiple grids and lists and other content and want it smooth? i cant put them inside a single SliverList because i have grids inside that need recycling behavior

Comment: it will work fine (of course if you have just few numbers of `SliverToBoxAdapter`s, not 100s)

Comment: @pskink its the way my apps written now, but im kinda interested to know how the engine behaves